# Time delay of texts in label in swift 3

Tags: ios, animation

I have a label. And I have 3 strings. I need to display text of 3 strings in the same label with delay of 10 seconds over a infinite loop. How can i solve this with simple animations in swift 3?

Comment: Your strings are declared as `Array`s. You'll want to remove the brackets from them. ex: `let str1: String = "PROFESSIONAL AND BEST LEARNING CENTER"`

Comment: ok  how can i do it now ?? @ Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for your, connect your outlet properly and declare those string in an array and load it with timer change.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

var array = ["Aaaaaaaaaaa", "Bbbbbbbbbbb", "Ccccccccccc"]
var scrollIndex = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.myDelayedFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer.fire()
}

func myDelayedFunction()-> Void {
let count = self.array.count
    if scrollIndex == count {
        scrollIndex = 0
    }
    if scrollIndex < count {
        if count > 1{
            self.label.text = array[scrollIndex]
            self.scrollIndex += 1
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: func myDelayedFunction()-> Void {
   
    let count = self.array.count
    if scrollIndex == count {
        scrollIndex = 0
    }
    if scrollIndex < count {
        if count > 1{
            self.label.text = array[scrollIndex]
         self.scrollIndex += 1
    }}    this one is the correct one. You can edit on your answer. @Subrat Padhi

Answer (score 1):

That's my solution. Just connect a UILabel to the IBOutlet

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    let messages = ["PROFESSIONAL AND BEST LEARNING CENTER","LEARNING TECHNOLOGY AND DESIGN IN A SMART WAY","EXPLORE YOUR SKILLS"]
    let delayTime = 10.0
    var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: delayTime, target: self, selector: #selector(changeDisplayedText), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
    }

    func changeDisplayedText() {
        textLabel.text = messages[counter % messages.count]
        counter += 1
    }
}
```